# sqldf() fails with "could not find function "sqldf" error

Tags: r

The following is the code I want to run. This is a code from Coursera. I am unable to run the sqldf function in this code:-

```
data = read.delim(file = 'purchases.txt', header = FALSE, sep = '\t', dec = '.')
str(data)

colnames(data) = c('customer_id', 'purchase_amount', 'date_of_purchase')
data$date_of_purchase = as.Date(data$date_of_purchase, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$days_since       = as.numeric(difftime(time1 = "2016-01-01",
                                        time2 = data$date_of_purchase,
                                        units = "days"))

head(data)
summary(data)

library(sqldf)

customers = sqldf("SELECT customer_id ,
                      MIN(days_since) AS 'recency',
                      COUNT(*) AS 'frequency',
                      AVG(purchase_amount) AS 'amount'
               FROM data GROUP BY 1")
```

Comment: Can I use data tables instead for the above query? How?

Answer (score 1):

One must have the `sqldf` package installed in R to use the `sqldf()` function after loading it with the `library()` function.

To install `sqldf` in R, use the `install.packages()` function.

Here is a completely reproducible version of the OP code, including `install.packages()` to install `sqldf`:

```
textFile <- "
001,42.5,2017-01-01
001,38.7,2017-05-02
002,47.9,2017-06-05"

# commented out original data read section
# data = read.delim(file = 'purchases.txt', header = FALSE, sep = '\t', dec = '.')
# str(data)

# replace with inline data and read.csv()
data <- read.csv(text=textFile,header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colnames(data) = c('customer_id', 'purchase_amount', 'date_of_purchase')
data$date_of_purchase = as.Date(data$date_of_purchase, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$days_since       = as.numeric(difftime(time1 = "2016-01-01",
                                            time2 = data$date_of_purchase,
                                            units = "days"))

head(data)
summary(data)

# only need to run install.packages() once
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)

customers = sqldf("SELECT customer_id ,
                      MIN(days_since) AS 'recency',
                      COUNT(*) AS 'frequency',
                      AVG(purchase_amount) AS 'amount'
               FROM data GROUP BY 1")
customers
```

...and the output:

```
> customers
  customer_id   recency frequency amount
1           1 -486.7917         2   40.6
2           2 -520.7917         1   47.9
>
```

Comment: Thank you Len. I am still getting the same error message. I am pasting the error below:- Error in sqldf("SELECT customer_id ,\n                      MIN(days_since) AS 'recency',\n                  COUNT(*) AS 'frequency',\n                  AVG(purchase_amount) AS 'amount'\n                  FROM data GROUP BY 1") : 
  could not find function "sqldf"

Comment: Could it be a problem with my RStudio? Do I need to reinstall RStudio?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to use install.packages() to install sqldf from the R console?

Comment: The package gets installed without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried to run R without RStudio, load sqldf and use it? If so, did you receive the same error message?

Comment: Did anyone find out how to resolve this? I am having the same issue and have tried reinstalling the package sqldf and reloading it, but it is still saying the function sqldf does not exist, even if I specify sqldf::sqldf()